# kotlin - using higher order functions in with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, intellij-idea

I ran into a weird issue when I was playing with kotlin+spring+hibernate, I’m pretty sure this is what’s causing problems:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> generateGetter(unknownValue: T): (String) -> T {
    return { s ->
        var res = unknownValue
        for (v in enumValues<T>()) {
            if (s == v.name) {
                res = v
                break
            }
        }
        res
    }
}
enum class Degree {
    Unknown,
    HighSchool,
    Bachelor,
    Master;
    companion object {
        val getEnum = generateGetter(Unknown)
    }
}
```

And I’d get this error when I ran ./gradlew bootRun:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not create DynamicParameterizedType for type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createParameterImpl(SimpleValue.java:766) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.x.tutor.model.Country]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createParameterImpl(SimpleValue.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/x/tutor/model/Country$$special$$inlined$generateGetter$1.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum; @60: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Enum' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @60
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/x/tutor/model/Country$$special$$inlined$generateGetter$1', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/Object', '[Lcom/x/tutor/model/Country;', integer, integer }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2b12 1fb8 0025 2ab4 0012 4db8 002b 4e2d
    0000010: be36 0403 3605 1505 1504 a200 212d 1505
    0000020: 323a 062b 1906 b600 31b8 0035 9900 0919
    0000030: 064d a700 0984 0501 a7ff de2c b0
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@22,{Object[#2],Object[#25],Object[#45],Object[#60],Integer,Integer},{})
    append_frame(@53,Object[#39])
    full_frame(@59,{Object[#2],Object[#25],Object[#62],Object[#60],Integer,Integer},{})
        at com.x.tutor.model.Country.<clinit>(Enums.kt:94) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

The weird thing is, the whole thing runs problem free if I use the run function provided by intellij

Does anyone know what caused this and how to resolve it?

Knowing that jetbrains developed kotlin, maybe there’s some crazy optimization they implemented in the kotlin plugin?

Comment: Why do you need generateGetter function? There is already Degree.valueOf(str) function that does the thing you need (converts string to enum, it throws exception if str is incorrect, but you can easily catch this exception and return default value).

Comment: pls show the usages of Degree.

Comment: @ardenit Although this is really not the point to be focused on, I wanted to skip the exception handling that I have to do every time I call valueOf and instead just return the Unknown value, which has the same name and makes copy-paste a lot easier.